# Error using soapcpp2 with an ONVIF header file generated with wsdl2h ( GSOAP with linux )

Tags: c, wsdl, gsoap, onvif

I'm trying to implement the onvif protocol on the camera side ( server ) with a microcontroller, without any implementation yet , I'm trying from the wsdl files of the onvif site ( such as http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl ) to generate the headers and the implementation files.

So I used gsoap , with the command `wsdl2h -c -o devicemgmt.h http://www.onvif.org/onvif/ver10/device/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl` , and it generates me the devicemgmt.h, Then when I do `soapcpp2 devicemgmt.h` I have

```
`devicemgmt.h(12328): syntax error
devicemgmt.h(12327): Syntax error: declaration expected
devicemgmt.h(12330): syntax error
devicemgmt.h(12329): Syntax error: declaration expected
devicemgmt.h(12332): syntax error
devicemgmt.h(12331): Syntax error: declaration expected
devicemgmt.h(12333): syntax error
devicemgmt.h(12339): Syntax error: declaration expected
devicemgmt.h(12342): syntax error
devicemgmt.h(12341): Syntax error: input before ; skipped
devicemgmt.h(12371): syntax error
devicemgmt.h(12370): Syntax error: declaration expected
devicemgmt.h(12373): syntax error
devicemgmt.h(12372): Syntax error: declaration expected
devicemgmt.h(12375): syntax error
devicemgmt.h(12374): Syntax error: declaration expected
devicemgmt.h(12377): syntax error
devicemgmt.h(12376): Syntax error: declaration expected
devicemgmt.h(12415): syntax error
devicemgmt.h(12414): Syntax error: declaration expected
devicemgmt.h(12417): syntax error
devicemgmt.h(12416): Syntax error: declaration expected
Critical error: too many syntactic errors, bailing out`
```

Here is the oportion of the header file where the errors are occuring :

```
 `/// "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2":NotificationMessageHolderType is a complexType.
struct ns4__NotificationMessageHolderType
{
/// Element reference "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2":SubscriptionReference.
///JUST BELOW THATS THE LINE 12328 WHERE THE ERROR IS 
ns1__EndpointReferenceType*          SubscriptionReference          0;  ///< Optional element.
    /// Element reference "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2":Topic.
        struct ns4__TopicExpressionType*     Topic                          0;  ///< Optional element.
    /// Element reference "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2":ProducerReference.
        ns1__EndpointReferenceType*          ProducerReference              0;  ///< Optional element.
        struct _ns4__NotificationMessageHolderType_Message
        {
    /// TODO: <any namespace="##any" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
    /// TODO: Schema extensibility is user-definable.
    ///       Consult the protocol documentation to change or insert declarations.
    ///       Use wsdl2h option -x to remove this element.
    ///       Use wsdl2h option -d for xsd__anyType DOM (soap_dom_element).
        _XML                                 __any                         0;   ///< Catch any element content in XML string.
        }                                    Message                        1;  ///< Required element.
    };


    /// Top-level root element "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2":NotificationProducerRP

    /// "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2":NotificationProducerRP is a complexType.
    struct _ns4__NotificationProducerRP
    {
    /// Size of the dynamic array of struct ns4__TopicExpressionType* is 0..unbounded
       $int                                  __sizeTopicExpression          0;
    /// Array struct ns4__TopicExpressionType* of length 0..unbounded
        struct ns4__TopicExpressionType*     TopicExpression                0;
    /// Element reference "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2":FixedTopicSet.
        enum xsd__boolean*                   FixedTopicSet                  0;  ///< Optional element.
    /// Size of the dynamic array of xsd__anyURI* is 0..unbounded
       $int                                  __sizeTopicExpressionDialect   0;
    /// Array xsd__anyURI* of length 0..unbounded
        xsd__anyURI*                         TopicExpressionDialect         0;
    /// Element reference "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/t-1":TopicSet.
        struct ns7__TopicSetType*            ns7__TopicSet                  0;  ///< Optional element.
    };


    /// Top-level root element "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2":SubscriptionManagerRP

    /// "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2":SubscriptionManagerRP is a complexType.
    struct _ns4__SubscriptionManagerRP
    {
    /// Element reference "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2":ConsumerReference.
        ns1__EndpointReferenceType           ConsumerReference              1;  ///< Required element.
    /// Element reference "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2":Filter.
        struct ns4__FilterType*              Filter                         0;  ///< Optional element.
    /// Element reference "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2":SubscriptionPolicy.
        struct ns4__SubscriptionPolicyType*  SubscriptionPolicy             0;  ///< Optional element.
    /// Element reference "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2":CreationTime.
        time_t*                              CreationTime                   0;  ///< Optional element.
    };


    /// Top-level root element "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2":Notify

    /// "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2":Notify is a complexType.
    struct _ns4__Notify
    {
    /// Size of the dynamic array of struct ns4__NotificationMessageHolderType* is 1..unbounded
       $int                                  __sizeNotificationMessage      1;
    /// Array struct ns4__NotificationMessageHolderType* of length 1..unbounded
        struct ns4__NotificationMessageHolderType*  NotificationMessage            1;
    /// TODO: <any namespace="##other" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    /// TODO: Schema extensibility is user-definable.
    ///       Consult the protocol documentation to change or insert declarations.
    ///       Use wsdl2h option -x to remove this element.
    ///       Use wsdl2h option -d for xsd__anyType DOM (soap_dom_element).
    /// Size of the array of XML or DOM nodes is 0..unbounded
       $int                                  __size                        0;
        _XML                                 __any                         0;   ///< Catch any element content in XML string.
    };


    /// Top-level root element "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2":UseRaw

    /// "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2":UseRaw is a complexType.
    struct _ns4__UseRaw
    {
    };


    /// Top-level root element "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2":Subscribe

    /// "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2":Subscribe is a complexType.
    struct _ns4__Subscribe
    {
    /// Element ConsumerReference of type "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing":EndpointReferenceType.
        ns1__EndpointReferenceType           ConsumerReference              1;  ///< Required element.
    /// Element Filter of type "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2":FilterType.
        struct ns4__FilterType*              Filter                         0;  ///< Optional element. `
```

Can someone help me please ? I don't know what to do , what's the problem with ns1__EndpointReferenceType and where is that syntaxe error ? what should I add to the Onvif headers if there is anything to add ?

Comment: Probably a problem with your typemap.dat, because I run your commands successfully. Did you look to [gSOAP FAQ](http://www.genivia.com/resources.html#How_do_I_use_gSOAP_with_the_ONVIF_specifications?) ?

Comment: Hi, I just looked in it, and I modified the typemap.dat file by adding the files that were not here, but It's always unsuccessful. I tried as well the commands that are proposed by the gSOAP FAQ but they don't work, can you help me to understand why?

Comment: When I add the commands of the FAQ I get an empty header, he says that he cannot open the typemap.dat

Comment: Did you use an old version of gSOAP ? Using gSOAP 2.8.17r from Ubuntu 15.04, it works without customisation of typemap.dat. Perhaps it culd be helpful that you add wsdl2h

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the `typemap.dat` that came with the gsoap 2.8.x distribution. This `typemap.dat` file includes the ONVIF bindings but also the WS-Addressing `wsa5.h` binding for the `EndpointReference` element:

```
#import "wsa5.h"
...
class wsnt__NotificationMessageHolderType
{ public:
  /// Element reference "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2:""http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsn/b-2":SubscriptionReference.
    wsa5__EndpointReferenceType*         SubscriptionReference          0;
```

Comment: Where do you get the gsoap 2.8.x distribution?

Comment: From SourceForge see also resources https://github.com/Genivia/gsoap